# Using a variable in a for command

Tags: bash

A newbie so please excuse

I use the below script to create copies of the same file

```
for i in {1..5}
 do 
  cp file xfs/file$i
 done
```

To create

file1
file2
file3
file4
file5

My Question is if i wanted to dictate how many files are created how do i do this

I have tried

read -p "How many files do you want" num

```
for i in {1..$num}
 do 
  cp file xfs/file$i
 done
```

I'm unsure on how to get the "for" command top accept my variable

Any ideas

Comment: FAQ Alert:  `for i in $(seq 1 $num)`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
for (( i=1; i<=$num; i++ )); 
    do 
        echo $i; 
done
```

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/